# Dialog do not show the Positive and Negative Button?

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

Why are the positive and negative buttons not shown on the app ?
Do you guys have any ideas what to change? thanks.

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    vibrator.vibrate(100);

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Berühre mich noch einmal und du wirst's bereuen!!");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK sorry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry Herr Gauß! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Mir egal.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Mehr als vibrieren kannst du eh nicht!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.create().show();
                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
                         }
            }
```

Comment: Try removing call to `create`method. So like `builder.show();`

Comment: It should work fine! why you have `dialogBuilder` this one? You don't use it  anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove last line you are creating new dialog again set theme on creating dialog

```
 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    vibrator.vibrate(100);

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
                    builder.setTitle("Berühre mich noch einmal und du wirst's bereuen!!");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK sorry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry Herr Gauß! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Mir egal.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Mehr als vibrieren kannst du eh nicht!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.create().show();

                         }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK sorry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry Herr Gauß! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .setTitle("Berühre mich noch einmal und du wirst's bereuen!!")
                    .setMessage("Hello world")
                    .show();
```